# IIS rewrite rule with exact match https url results in error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I've converted a site from ASP.NEt webforms to MVC 5 and have successfully written rules to redirect all the old .aspx pages -- except for the only encrypted page.

I would greatly appreciate help in correcting this rule, which results in net::ERR_CORRECTION_RESET

```
<rule name="https link" stopProcessing="true" patternSyntax="ExactMatch">
<match url="https://www.mysite.org/ssl/securedonation.aspx" />

 <action type="Redirect" url="/donate/" redirectType="Permanent"/>
</rule>
```

I suspect I need to add a condition, but have not been able to figure out its syntax or function.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to add a condition if you only want to match on https and not http for example. But in your case I would think this doesn't matter. You can just redirect the securedonation.aspx page to /donate/, there's no need to treat this any differently just because it uses https. Try this:

```
<rule name="https link" stopProcessing="true" patternSyntax="ExactMatch">
    <match url="ssl/securedonation.aspx" />

    <action type="Redirect" url="/donate/" redirectType="Permanent"/>
</rule>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this behaves the same way as my illustration. The https link results in net::ERR_CORRECTION_RESET . In fact, any https link , including https://mysite.org results in the same error.

Comment: Hum that doesn't sound like a redirect rule issue then. Are you sure the SSL certificate is installed correctly? Do other users have the same issue? Does this link help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9orMZyky-UI

Comment: That YouTube deals with fixing an error on a personal computer. This is a public-facing website that, in its old version, had an encrypted page (https). The new site does not have any encrypted content, thus no certificate. Any https requests to the new site result in that error -- in all browsers and on all devices that I've tested.

Comment: Ahh I see. Yeah you won't be able to fix that unless you install an SSL certificate so that the server can respond with https. When a web request comes in, it first tries to respond on the same protocol, https in this case. If the server can't respond on that protocol you will get a connection error. It won't even get to the rewrite rules.

Comment: So I've been forced to conclude. Appreciate your explanation.